# Can we pass space as value in arguments? Java

Tags: java

Suppose, if we have to pass two values from terminal to a java program, value will be treated as String in program. What if the values are spaces. How do we pass them without any need to treat them separately inside the program?

Comment: Put the value in quotes: `java MyProgram "foo bar"`

Comment: @SaagarJha - the value is only space like " ", no words, no characters

Comment: `java MyProgram " "` should do the trick.

Comment: Not a Java question. This is the same for any program executed from a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotation marks to wrap your arguments so that the shell you are using does not interpret them as separate arguments.

Comment: Will passing the space in quotation require extra processing in the program? or it will take value as with quotation?

Comment: No, it will take the value that is within the quotes.  You must escape the quotes if you want to pass them into the program as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question in response to Saagar Jha in your question's comment's section.

```
java MyApp " "
```

Simply enclose the space character between two double-quotes to pass it to your app's `main` method.

Comment: if I am passing it that way, then won't the program require extra processing to remove the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass argument values which contains only whitespaces?

Just pass the whitespaces between `""`.

For example here :  `java yourProgram " " " "` you pass two arguments (each one is a whitespace)